# How do I get pixel information from a FITs image in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to find the intensities of given pixels in a FITs image in Python. The image is black and white so I'm only looking for the values of the pixels.

The code I'm using is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astropy
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('jet.fits')
image_data = fits.getdata(image_file,ext=0)
image = fits.open('jet.fits')
image.info()
image_data[400][500] #the 400 being the x coordinate of the pixel and the #500 being the y coordinate of the pixel
```

The last line gives me an output which I am assuming is the value of the pixel, however I get a value of around 109 instead of a value around 0 as the pixel in the image in black or very close to it.

I have tried taking (0,0) as both the upper left corner of the picture and the lower left corner and neither get 0.

I have also tried using PIL and skimage to get the value of the pixel but both result in an "cannot find loader for this fits file" error when I try and open the image.

Any suggestions on how I can get the pixel value?

Comment: That code should work fine to give the data values. Astronomical FITS files can have a very narrow range of image data values and can appear black in image viewers which are not designed for FITS. Can you try opening the image in sometimes like ds9 (or other [fits viewers](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_viewer.html)) and confirming the pixel values match astropy

Comment: Maybe you could share the image so folk can assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

(0,0) might be the position of the lower left corner and the x and y axis in image_data are reversed (image_data[y][x]). See: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/image.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30737303)